# How to make Camel's "Netty4" component output an endpoint's results, but NOT echo back all the input as well?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, netty, spring-camel

I am experimenting with using Apache Camel to implement a TCP game server.  It will accept bi-directional, synchronous telnet or SSH connections from multiple human or bot players.

The communication "protocol" is a bit crude, and based on legacy infrastructure that's already in place from an earlier version.  Basically, the client and server exchange I/O over a socket (one connection per client).

Usually, this consists of one-line command strings, or one-line response strings.  However, in some cases the input or output can span multiple line breaks before it is considered "complete" and ready for the other side's response.  So my plan is to:

1. Create a TCP socket server using Spring Boot and Apache Camel, with the latter's "Netty4" component.
2. Use aggregation to collect the incoming lines of text from a socket connection.  Roll them up into messages of one or more lines, depending on the type of input detected.
3. Pass the resulting message to an endpoint, which parses the input and returns the appropriate response back to the socket.

I can show any other code or Spring config, but the heart of my question seems to be the route I'm declaring:

```java
@Component
public class EchoRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        // "sync=true" seems necessary to return any response to the client at all
        //
        // "textline=true&autoAppendDelimiter=false" seem necessary to properly handle 
        //     the socket input at newline-terminated strings, rather than processing 
        //     input byte-by-byte
        from("netty4:tcp://localhost:4321?sync=true&textline=true&autoAppendDelimiter=false")

                // This line, and the corresponding `.header("incoming")` line below, are 
                // perhaps a bit dodgy.  I'm assuming that all messages on the route 
                // from a given client socket are already effectively "correlated", and 
                // that messages from multiple client sockets are not inter-mingled 
                // here.  So I'm basically wildcard-ing the correlation mechanism.  If my 
                // assumption is wrong, then I'm not sure how to correlate by
                // client socket.
                .setHeader("incoming", constant(true))

                // Taken from numerous examples I've seen in Camel books and website 
                // pages.  Just concatenates the correlated messages until 
                // completion occurs.
                .aggregate(new AggregationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                        if (oldExchange == null) {
                            return newExchange;
                        }
                        final String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        final String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldBody + newBody);
                        return oldExchange;
                    }
                })

                // See comment on "setHeader(...) above.
                .header("incoming")

                // In this initial testing, aggregation of a particular message is 
                // considered complete when the last line received is "EOM".
                .completionPredicate(exchange -> {
                    final String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    final boolean done = body.endsWith("EOM");
                    return done;
                })

                // This endpoint will eventually parse the aggregated message and 
                // perform logic on it.  Right now, it just returning the input message 
                // with a prefix.
                .to("bean:echoService");                 

    }
}
```

When I start my server, and telnet to port `4321` from a separate terminal window, I can verify in the debugger that:

1. The `.completetionPredicate(...)` logic is being invoked upon each line of input as expected, and
2. The `echoService` endpoint is being invoked as expected after an `EOM` line of input.  The message passed to the endpoint contains the expected aggregated content.

However, there are two problems:

1. The server is **echoing each line of input** back to the client connection, rather than letting the endpoint determine the response content.
2. The server is **not sending the endpoint return value** to the client.  I log it to the server console, but otherwise it's silently discarded.

Any suggestions on what I might be missing here?  The desired behavior is for the route to send the endpoint's return value to the client socket, and nothing but the endpoint's return value.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems that the aggregator is replying to your client after each exchange processing. If you try something smaller, without the aggregator and set the response OUT body you will receive the correct reply. The aggregator aren't "holding" the processing until it finishes and are returning the handle to the caller. I think this is the expected behavior since it supposed to process a lot of messages from a bunch of clients.